# Cómo abrir puerto serie en cliente Linux desde escritorio remoto en Windows?

Tags: c#, linux, rdp, serialport

Tengo un programa desarrollado en **C#** que lee un dato de un lector de tarjetas conectado al puerto serie. El programa está instalado en un servidor **windows**. Todos los clientes que ejecutan el programa lo hacen a través de sesiones de escritorio remoto, cada cliente tiene su archivo `rdp` donde se explicita que se puede acceder a los puertos `COM` locales. Hasta aquí todo va bien.

Ahora, tengo un cliente **Linux** que abre una sesión de escritorio remoto en el servidor **Windows** por medio del comando `rdesktop`, donde entre otros parámetros especificamos que queremos usar el puerto serie de la siguiente manera:

```
-comport: COM1=/dev/ttyS0
```

Pues bien, al abrir el puerto serie da el siguiente error:

```
El nombre de puerto proporcionado no es válido
```

Puede ser un puerto válido, pero no es un puerto serie.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort puerto = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1");
// Inicializo el resto de parámetros con valores ordinarios
puerto.Open() // Aquí se produce el error
```

¿Alguien me puede dar alguna pista de lo que sucede?
¿Falta alguna configuración en el cliente **Linux**?
¿Puede que sea un bug de la librería **.NET**?